# Using ADODB recordsets with both MS Access and MariaDB in VB.net simultaneously

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mariadb, adodb

We have a very large in-house Visual Basic Windows Form app built on .net 3.5 (currently maintained with Visual Studio 2019 v16.11) that stores data in an old, very large (>1GB), MS Access 'mdb' extension file. We would like to eventually have these data completely stored in a MariaDB (MySQL) database and do away with the MS Access file. The app handles tables through ADODB recordsets and uses recordset methods and properties to read and modify data where a simpler SQL statement might suffice and even be better practice. However changing the code not to use recordsets just isn't an option as there are over 190,000 lines of code - ADODB recordsets must continue to be used.

We would like to have the app handle both the old MS Access and new MariaDB databases at the same time in the same way with recordsets. This way, we can incrementally 'move' tables to MariaDB and iron out any problems that might occur table by table.

The problem is that when executing the following code to use the MariaDB:

```
cnMariaDB = New ADODB.Connection

cnMariaDB.ConnectionString =
"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};" _
& "Port=3306;" _
& "SERVER=192.1.2.3;" _
& "DATABASE=XYZDatabase;" _
& "UID=XYZUser;PWD=XYZPswd; OPTION=3"

cnMariaDB.Open()
```

An exception is thrown at 'cnMariaDB.Open()': {"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

If I change the 'Target CPU' from 'x86' to 'AnyCPU' the above code works or at least does not explicitly error. However, the old code to use the MS Access file:

```
cnRDM = New ADODB.Connection

cnRDM.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
cnRDM.Properties("Data Source").Value = "J:\XYZData.mdb"
cnRDM.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password").Value = "XYZsecret"

cnRDM.Open()
```

gives this exception: {"Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."}   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The order in which these 2 blocks of code execute doesn't make a difference. Again, if I set the Target CPU to AnyCPU, opening the MariaDB connection (appears to) work but opening the MS Access connection fails and vice versa if Target CPU is set to x86.

What I've tried so far:
-Differing frameworks: 3.5 and 4.7 (btw, I didn't convert the existing project to 4.7, but tried on a small 'test' VB project)
-Tried 'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}' in the MariaDB connection string.
-Tried 2 different ADODB.dll files, 7.10.3077 and

What I haven't tried so far:

1. upgrading to Visual Studio '22 (version
2. different 'OPTION's in the MariaDB connection string

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following removed post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590149/using-recordset-methods-e-g-addnew-update-on-mysql-in-vb-net

Comment: _We would like to have the app handle both the old MS Access and new MariaDB databases at the same time in the same way with recordsets_: This isn't possible. As the comments stated in your previous post, [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) is what's used now, not _ADO_.

Comment: I have posted detailed info about the problem, jumped through the hoops and I've done what I can do in so far as trying everything I know and I get tantalizingly close to a solution - so this is a valid request for help. Regardless of whether it should be or not, ADO can still be used 'now'. THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!

Comment: and the down vote, HELPS A BUNCH

Comment: and the name 'tu deschizi eu inchid', that's so mysterious! but I bet if I pasted that into Google Translate it would translate as SUPER HELPFUL NICE GUY (or GAL, don't want to assume gender)

Comment: and you have stackoverflow badges! I guess for begin so helpful?! that is SO cool!

Comment: It sounds like that ODBC driver is only 64-bit while the ACE OLE DB provider is only 32-bit. Not sure whether you can get the driver in a 32-bit edition but you can install 64-bit ACE. If replacing the ACE you have is not an option, you can install both if they are different versions, e.g. I have 64-bit Microsoft 365 and I installed 32-bit ACE from Office 2010.

Comment: Honest opinion based on experience.  What you are proposing here is plain the worst possible way to do it and will cause you significant pain.  You really are far better off biting the bullet and just do the whole thing in one hit.  With only 190k lines of code, a decently constructed DAL,  you should really be able to knock this out in a matter of days

Answer (score 0):

> If I change the 'Target CPU' from 'x86' to 'AnyCPU' the above code works or at least does not explicitly error.

Ok, you have to sort that issue out. vs2019 came in 2 versions, a x32 bit version, and a x64 bit version. So, you have to check if you running x64 bit version of vs2019.

You actually have to address this issue. A guess based on the confection working with ANY cpu?

This suggests that your MySQL/MariaDB driver is ONLY x64 bits, but then the drivers for access (the ACE data engine) are x32 bits.

So, either way? You REALLY need to ALWAYS force the project to run as a "known" bit size.

In vs2022, since it is x64 bit product now (by default), then ANY CPU results in a x64 bit "in process" running application.

In previous versions of vs, ANY CPU results in a x32 bit running application.

The exception here is vs2019, since it came in 2 flavors.

Regardless of the "potential" confusing issue of ANY CPU?

I would suggest because ms-access data engine is involved here?

You have to ALWAYS force the bit size of your project. It does not matter if you pick x64, or x86 (x32 bits), but you need to fix and force this issue.

So, either you:

Install the x64 bit Maria db drivers. Or the ms-access ACE drivers as x64 bits.

Or, you install the x32 bit Maria db drivers, and then install + use the x32 (x86) version of the Access "ACE" engine.

From your post, my best guess is that you don't have the Maria x32 bit version of their drivers installed.

You also don't note if any of the moving parts of this application means that some ms-access application is being run, or the vb.net application ONLY uses a ms-access database, and ms-access as a product/application is not being used here.

So, you can install ms-acess runtime, or ONLY the ACE database engine. For  your case, probably the "latter" is ok.

Last but not least?

since this is a "mdb" file, then  you could commit to using the older JET database engine That data engine (JET as opposed to ACE) is rather legacy, only comes in x32 bit flavor, and can open "mdb" files, but cannot open the newer accDB file formats (you need ACE data engine for that).

Why consider and use the JET data engine over ACE?

Well, since about windows 98 - a VERY long time ago, the windows OS includes a copy of JET by default. Even the new version of windows 11, or even a brand new server edition of windows includes the JET data engine, and all "OS" installs since about windows 98 to this day includes the JET engine.

As a result, you can be "sure" that the target computer, or even your existing computer without ANY additional software being installed, it can and will consume and open the mdb files, and do so without any additional software having been installed.

However, for your software to work, then you must force and run your .net project as x32 bits. This also means you can continue to use the connection strings with "JET" as opposed to now having to use "ACE" data engine in those connection strings.

So, to make a long story short?

It looks like you don't have the x32 bit version of the Maria/MySQL driver installed.

Get that driver installed, and then you can with confidence force your project to x32 (x86). Since depending on the version of VS, and your computer set, using ANY CPU means from computer to computer, and from version of VS to latter versions, you not know if when hitting F5 to run that you get a x32 bit "in-process" running program, or a x64 bit "in-process" running program.

In effect, I am saying you want to force the project to a given bit size, and do so at all times during development, and during deployment.

Last but not least?

Since you may well need or at some point in time open the database with ms-access? (maybe to compact + repair, change table designs etc.)? I would consider at one point in time to switch over to using an accDB file format, since already some versions of the latest versions of office/Access are having difficulty reading and using the VERY old "mdb" file format now.

However, for the time being, if a JET connection opens the mdb file, then stick with that for the time being.